# Establecer imagen como background de layout indicando el nombre de la imagen en un String

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy haciendo una aplicación sencilla y me encuentro con que no soy capaz de cambiar el fondo a un layout indicando el nombre de la imagen en cuestión por String.

El código que tengo es este:

```
fondo.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ff);
```

Donde "ff" es el nombre de la imagen que ya tengo guardada como recurso ("ff.jpg"). Así funciona perfectamente.
Lo que me gustaría es que esa "ff" fuera suministrada por medio de un String. Algo así:

```
miString="ff.jpg";
fondoJuego.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.miString);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar, sin la extension de la imagen, en este caso :

```
String miString = "ff";

int resource = getResources().getIdentifier(miString, "drawable", getPackageName());
fondoJuego.setBackGroundResource(resource);
```

Segun la documentación de android :

> getResource : Devuelve una instancia de los recursos para el package de la aplicación.
>   getIdentifier : Devuelve un identificador de recursos para un nombre especifico. Los parametros son :

- name : Nombre del recurso
- defType : El tipo de recurso, este es opcional en el caso que en el parametro anterior ya este especificado.
- defPackage : El package especifico de donde quieres obtener dicho recurso.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias :).